# What is the Java type that can receive MULTIPART_FORM_DATA?

Tags: jax-rs

I'm making a REST service which should receive a file (from Postman) as Multipart type, I know i can receive the file as "File" or "InputStream" but they come with extra characters and stuff like:

-------------48574845 
content-type: idk
other-thing: idkeither

THE ACTUAL FILE GOES HERE

--------------345345345

I want to save that incoming file to the server

I've been googleing for days, found many answers here in StackOverflow BUT:
-I should not use Spring or any framework.
-I tried with IAttachment and MultiPartBody, @RequestFormParams and other things, nothin works.
-Im not familiar with Maven, i tried but when I use it my rest doens't even work

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String getXml(@QueryParam("age") String age, InputStream file) throws IOException {

}
```

This is what i  got so far

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have on how you currently implement the REST service or how you define your controller/actions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it after weeks.
all you need is this beautiful thing called "import javax.mail.Multipart;"

```
    MimeBodyPart parsedFile= new MimeBodyPart(file);
    saveToFile(parsedFile.getInputStream(),parsedFile.getFileName());
    return "hey i FINALLY DID IT";
```